# Start-Job script block-- how to call cmdlets with arguments?

Tags: powershell, arguments, powershell-cmdlet, start-job

I'm new to the `Start-Job` cmdlet and am having trouble calling a script block with cmdlets in it that take arguments.  Here's what I have so far:

```
    Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
       $ServiceObj = Get-Service -Name $ServiceName -ComputerName $Computer -ErrorAction Stop   
       Stop-Service -InputObj $ServiceObj -erroraction stop 
    }
```

I'm seeing errors when I run `receive-job` that the `-ComputerName` argument is null or empty, and the `-InputObj` argument is null or empty.  In neither case is that so.  The snippet above is being called from inside two foreach loops:

```
foreach($Computer in $ComputerNames) {
  foreach($ServiceName in $ServiceNames) {
   #..call snippet above
  }
 }
```

I've tried using the `-ArgumentList` when calling my script block but no luck there either.  I'm sure I'm missing something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do need to use ArgumentList (unless you're on PowerShell V3) e.g.:

```
Start-Job -ScriptBlock {param($ComputerName)
   $ServiceObj = Get-Service -Name $ServiceName -CN $ComputerName -ErrorAction Stop
   Stop-Service -InputObj $ServiceObj -erroraction stop 
} -ArgumentList $Computer
```

If you're using PowerShell V3, you can use the `using` variable qualifier e.g.:

```
Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
   $ServiceObj = Get-Service -Name $ServiceName -CN $using:Computer -ErrorAction Stop
   Stop-Service -InputObj $ServiceObj -erroraction stop 
}
```

Comment: Thank you Keith.  I had neglected to add the param($..) bit at the start of the script.  May I ask how I can pass in a splatted variable, whereby in addition to `$Computer` above I'm also passing in a variable named `FORCESTOP`, defined in the main script like so: `$FORCESTOP = @{force=$force}`

Comment: Splatting is an operation that you do on a cmdlet from a hashtable. Just pass in a hashtable of parameters and you can then splat that hashtable onto an command.  You could pass in the parameters individually e.g. `params($ComputerName, [switch]$ForceStop)`...